# Github .pdf diffs

Tags: git, pdf, github

In one of my GitHub repositories I have a .pdf file, which gets updated frequently. The problem is in the GitHub commits page, which shows the diff for this pdf. As pdfs are mostly binary the diff is long and so the page works very slowly and is useless for a quick peek as to what has changed between commits.

Is there a way to convince GitHub to hide the diffs for a certain file type or something along those lines?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding this to your `.gitattributes`:

```
*.pdf binary
```

Then commit the attributes file.

Comment: I added a .gitattribtues with only that text in & committed the file. It exists on the root where my .gitignore is but pdf files are stilling showing up in the PR diffs. Any suggestions?